# I have a .h file that contains structs&macros I want to use in a C# application. How do I include the .h file?

Tags: c#-4.0

Can you provide a simple example or a link to a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you are trying to accomplish.  There is no way to include the headers directly in any meaningful way in a C# project.  C# doesn't use header files and compiles to IL.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/5df04db1-bbc8-4389-b752-802bc84148fe) is a link describing the various interop methods between managed and unmanaged code if you are seeking to consume e.g. an unmanaged library in C#.  A search for PInvoke will turn up more references.

Edit: [Better link to an SO post with more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425752/managed-c-wrappers-for-legacy-c-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You need to manually port the `struct`s to C# `struct`s with attributes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no C# version of a macro from C++ or C.  You'll need to make actual methods in C# to do the same operations.

The structs will need to be ported to C# struct types, as well.  You cannot include a C or C++ header file into a C# program directly.

The methods that use the structs from the C or C++ DLL can be called from C#, if required, via Platform Invocation.

For details, see the MSDN Section on [Consuming Unmanaged DLL Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26thfadc.aspx).